# Typescript, from us currency to es currency

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert an us currency to a spanish currency (ok) but when I try to get again the us currency I get a Nan. What's wrong?

Thanks

```
const esp = Number('5000.55').toLocaleString(); // esp = '5.000,55'
const us = Number('5.000,55').toLocaleString('en-US'); // us = 'NaN'
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to HRK44's answer I would suggest using [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) which is part of the Internationalization API. `.toLocaleString` is older, it does not actually support locale, it just uses system locale and performs way worse with bulk data.

You can then perform the conversion like below using appropriate language code:

```
var CurrencyFormat= new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
});

CurrencyFormat.format(5000.55); /* $5,500.55 */
```

Comment: The problem is that the user will insert '5.000,55' value and I cannot convert it to us currency.

Comment: @sklmpg as I said in my answer, if you allow the user to input '5.000,55' then you will need to use a 3rd party library (like https://github.com/BenjaminVanRyseghem/numbro or accounting.js) or parse it yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to use accounting.js but I cannot fin any example. Big thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Number('5.000,55')` is not correct -> it returns NaN.

There is no native js function to get the number from the `.toLocaleString()` result.

What you could do :

1 - Save the initial value into a variable :

```
const init = '5000.55';
const esp = Number(init).toLocaleString(); // esp = '5.000,55'
const us = Number(init).toLocaleString('en-US'); // us = '5,000.55'
```

2 - Use some 3rd party library that deal with number manipulation.

3 - Create your own function that parses the result into whatever you like (might be hard to deal with all cases...)